# Not able to get webpack integrated with my react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have the following directory structure for a react app I've created to learn it.  I've been successfully running the app locally using `sudo npm start` without a problem but now I need to look at file compression and production readiness.  I'm trying to incorporate webpack although I'm failing to get it working.  I've included my package.json file below.

Reading a large number of articles, watching videos and questions on SO I've tried `npm run build` although I receive the errors below.

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks,

**Errors received when loading npm run build**

```
> webpack --mode production

Hash: 5f183040822e4fd0a9b9
Version: webpack 4.31.0
Time: 284ms
Built at: 
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js 284 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
| registerServiceWorker();
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
```

Looking at the error message I've removed the registerServiceWork references but after running `npm run build` I see the following error message.

**Second attempt**

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import App from './App';
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
|
```

**Directory structure**

```
-src
---index.js
---app.js
-build.sh
-package.json
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.4",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "public-ip": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0",
    "react-number-format": "^4.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
    "recharts": "^1.5.0",
    "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=80 react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "bundlesize",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bundlesize": "^0.17.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^3.0.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

For completeness index.js is included below.

**/src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: are you using custom webpack with create-react-app?

Comment: Yes, I believe so although I created it 6 months ago but if my memory serves me right yes it was using create-react-app

Comment: you don't use custom webpack with create-react-app. You can eject the app if you want to see what's inside create-react-app. It's a one-way move, so be careful. (see scripts -> eject)

Comment: When you say 'whats inside create-react-app' are you referring to compression and seeing what dependencies are the largest files?  Also, are you saying if it was created using crate-react-app that it doesn't use webpack?

Comment: I mean the configuration, I guess (haven't checked it thoroughly myself) create-react-app is using webpack under the hood, so you might want to eject to see their webpack configuration, and you edit there, not by creating a new webpack configuration.

Comment: is there a react template that I should use that comes with webpack that's not under the hood and maybe I can load my files into the new template?

Comment: as far as I know, if you're using create-react-app in the beginning, you shouldn't and don't create custom webpack configuration. If you want to use custom webpack, remove the create-react-app like, say, build a new project and move all your source there without create-react-app specific items, or eject and edit the internal configuration as I said before. There are many non-create-react-app webpack configuration available on the internet, you might want to search those first. (see keyword: `webpack react boilerplate`)

Comment: I'm experimenting with it now to see.